# Back button and pagination - state not saved

Tags: discussion

On SO, after paging through X number of pages using the pagination menu, then viewing a question...Hitting the back button returns to the initial page listing of questions but back to page 1 - is this a known bug? By design?

Comment: Thanks @nicael - same question, I couldn't find it